# Remove a letter, make a new word

Tags: wordplay, word-game

I have created a new puzzle, very similar to anagram puzzles.

You will be given several lines to solve in order to finally solve the puzzle! For example,

> "He's ____, and he's never coming back," he said. "I know he was the best ___ a son could ever have, but you have to let go and move on."

You have to pick a word that will fit the first blank (in this case, it must have 4 letters), and then take out one letter to make a new word that can fit the second blank. Now it can't be the plural letter S (or D, or Y) because that just ruins the fun.

> "He's $\underline{dead}$, and he's never coming back," he said. "It was a terrible thing. He was the best $\underline{dad}$ a son could ever have, but you have to let go and move on." 
>  
>  Therefore, the letter taken out is E.

Now who is *he* in the line above? Well, there will be more lines with words that must be filled. Once you take out all the letters of each line and sort them together in a corresponding row, you will make a name. That is *his* name.

Another entire example,

> "According to my calculations, the ghost will _____ the chapel," he said. "Let's finish this ____ once and for all!" $$\Downarrow$$ "According to my calculations, the ghost will $\underline{haunt}$ the chapel," he said. "Let's finish this $\underline{hunt}$ once and for all!"
>  
>  Missing letter: A.

> He drew the plans on a _____, before dropping in for a quick ____. $$\Downarrow$$ He drew the plans on a $\underline{chart}$, before dropping in for a quick $\underline{chat}$. 
>  
>  Missing letter: R

> He knew that if he did not go on the ____, he would ___. $$\Downarrow$$ He knew that if he did not go on the $\underline{diet}$, he would $\underline{die}$. 
>  
>  Missing letter: T.

Therefore, his name is A R T $\to$ Art.

---

## Puzzle:

> "You can't go on the ____ with a hat on," her mother said. "It will fly off. Give it to me." But her dad said, "Nah, it doesn't suit you anyway. Just get ___ of it.

> She had no idea that the house____ was an expert in first ___.

> "____, how hungry are ya?" she said. "You already ___ three bowls!"

> "What does the ____ feel like?" the doctor said. She replied, "It feels like ___s and needles."

***What is her name?***

---

To any expert puzzle-makers/developers, is there anything I could work on to make this puzzle better? Feedback is much appreciated!

Comment: (The word-problem tag is for math problems stated as story such as "Three workers build two houses in five weeks,..." The puzzle-creation tag is for questions about creating puzzles, not for puzzles you've already created for us to solve. I think just wordplay is fine.)

Comment: @MOehm okay, thanks for that. I will remove the tags... and done!

Comment: I liked the puzzle, seems to be a fun one.

Comment: "A puzzle" seems like far too common name, which is dangerous here. Puzzles of this kind tend to produce a fad and a wave of similar typed (thus, similar named) puzzles. Looking at the nature of this one, I would suggest a word "pzzle".

Comment: Interesting new puzzle. Is this gonna replace the Riley Riddle :) ?

Comment: [I have invented a manoeuvre!](https://scroll.in/video/824570/watch-comic-eddie-izzard-offers-an-unreliable-explanation-of-the-origin-of-the-heimlich-manoeuvre)

Comment: "ReduceAgram" ?

Comment: I like it! You could make variations where there are more words missing from the sentence too.

Comment: I like this type, and it seems to be much better at ensuring a single answer than some of the blanket riddles we see a lot , although I never did know the community stance on how we like those. It was clever of you to use language learning / SAT writing problems as a puzzle format

Comment: Rid-dle? There are a great many word pairs that are a possible answer, so the wording has to be very precise to avoid duplicate answers.

Comment: @ThomasBlue thanks for letting me know. I definitely like that idea :)

Comment: @Chowzen that seems good. Combining **Thomas Blue**'s idea, I can write *"A ReduceAgram Pzzle"* :D

Comment: @Ruadhan2300 will do, but I will have all the lines in one puzzle have words where you must take out the same amount of letters. Otherwise, it might be too difficult and can be too broad. There are three answers below when I expected only one, as well, so I might have to change my sentences to make them more specific.

Comment: @Bass Nice idea (because you are ridding the letters) but I don't think this is a *riddle*. I will, however, take into consideration of making the wording precise, so thank you for that :)

Comment: @theREALyumdub thank you for that, but it was originally [**QuantumTwinkie**](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/34530/quantumtwinkie) who came up with this puzzle format in his/her anagram puzzles. I just built from that after making three anagram puzzles myself, inspired by his/her work :)

Comment: I think if the result is no name, something more specific you will eliminate the "to broad". It would be cool if the result would also be a ReduceAgram.

Comment: _Name: Drop names?_

Comment: @Doomenik okay. I just wanted to add some kind of story or objective to the puzzle, to make it a bit more original. Thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: @u_ndefined see my comment above :)

Comment: @KevinL I don't know... will it? :P

Comment: Maybe, Maybe not :)

Comment: this one was a nice concept as well,you could make more of these.

Comment: @ShahriarMahmudSajid yeah, I have a few in mind. I am currently gathering a list :P

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Wow this puzzle is pretty fun! Nice one :)

1. > ride, rid 
   >  Letter removed is E
2. > maid, aid 
   >  Letter removed is M
3. > mate, ate 
   >  Letter removed is M
4. > pain, pin 
   >  Letter removed is A

So the girl's name is

> EMMA

Comment: Yup, you got it! I wanted to start easy so just so I could get an idea of how the community would react to this type of puzzle. Are there any improvements that I can make apart from the difficulty, of course? Or is there anything else you suggest? (I would also upvote if I didn't reach my daily voting limit...)

Comment: @user477343 I can really imagine these kinds of puzzles being legit and fun. Quite an interesting variant of the anagram puzzle, and the above suggested names are great btw ;) I think if you could do questions with multiple words (like with the anagrams) that would be awesome, but then I think it might be more difficult to do multiple words with this than with the anagrams.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! Yes, this proved to be a little more difficult, but English has heaps of weird spellings that might just come to my aid. (I mean, I thought I would never be able to make another anagram puzzle, but I currently am right now, namely, my fourth one!). But there's also one other thing that has been proved: this answer deserves the tick! Congratulations!! $\;\color{green}{\checkmark}$

Answer (score 1):

My take on it:

1. > ride, rid 
   >  Letter removed is E
2. > maid, aid 
   >  Letter removed is M
3. > Kate, ate 
   >  Letter removed is K
4. > pain, pin 
   >  Letter removed is A

Her name is

> EMKA

Comment: I've never heard of anyone by that name, sounds eastern-european though.

Comment: Balkans I think.

Comment: @ViktorMellgren according to [this site](http://www.namepedia.org/en/firstname/Emka/) it is definitely female, and sounds closest to Croatian or Bosnian.

Comment: @Ruadhan2300 I have never heard of it either, but you can look at my comment above :)

Comment: No, that was not the intended answer. But it works. I might have to change my wording to be a little bit more precise. $(+1)$ nonetheless :)

Comment: To be honest I solved it with these letters, then searched if it was an actual name :D

Comment: Yes, it is an actual name. When I was a kid (or to be more precise, a younger kid), I used to watch a TV show called [*The Fairly OddParents!*](http://fairlyoddparents.wikia.com/wiki/The_Fairly_OddParents!) where there are characters called [Tad and **Chad**](http://nickelodeon.wikia.com/wiki/Tad_and_Chad), so it's definitely a name :D

Answer (score 1):

I thought of it like this:

> Rid,Ride; Missing Letter: E
> Maid,Aid; Missing Letter: M
> Chad,Had; Missing Letter: C
> Pain,Pin; Missing Letter: A

Comment: Hello! Welcome to the **Puzzling Stack Exchange (Puzzling.SE)**. This was not the intended answer, but it works, so I have to give it to ya (though I have never heard of the name EMCA before). $(+1)$. Since you are new, I strongly suggest you visit the [**Help Center**](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help), and in particularly visit the following three sections: *Asking* (e.g. [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)), *Answering* (e.g. [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)) and *Our model* (e.g. [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/conduct)).